# When inverting a transfer function, solving for the input using the output does the causality status change

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, transfer-function, stability, causality

suppose $y(n)=ax(n-1)+bx(n-2)+\dots$  ($y$ is the output and $x$ the input). What happens if I want to solve $x(n)$ from $y(n)$?

Z transform: $$Y(z)=G(z)X(z)\tag{1}$$
then         $$X(z)=\frac{1}{G(z)}Y(z)\tag{2}$$

What are the properties of $1/G(z)$ ? If $(1)$ is causal what is the status of the inverse $(2)$? The roles  of the poles and zeros have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've pointed out, inversion leads to poles at locations of the zeros of the original transfer function and vice versa. Assuming that $G(z)$ is causal and stable (i.e., it has all its poles inside the unit circle), we have to distinguish $3$ cases:

1. $G(z)$ has at least some zeros outside the unit circle. This means its inverse has some poles outside the unit circle, and consequently, it cannot be causal *and* stable. If $G(z)$ has no zeros *on* the unit circle, there exists a stable impulse response corresponding to $1/G(z)$ but it cannot be causal. This is because a transfer function does not uniquely determine an impulse response. We can get different impulse responses corresponding to different regions of convergence of $1/G(z)$.
2. $G(z)$ has some of its zeros on the unit circle. No stable inverse exists because $1/G(z)$ has poles on the unit circle.
3. $G(z)$ has all its zeros inside the unit circle, i.e., it is a minimum-phase system. Consequently, $1/G(z)$ also has all its poles and zeros inside the unit circle (i.e., it is minimum-phase), and can be implemented by a causal and stable system.

Comment: I see, let me explain further...G(z) has only one pole at z=0 and the magnitudes of all the  zeros lie outside the  unit circle (nothing on) - when I interpret the poles of (1/G(z))  in closed form - is it the anti-causal interpretation (a)^n u(-n-1)? Since y(n) is calculated in terms of past x(n) - but now x(n) is in terms of past/future y(n)?

Comment: @Michelle: If $1/G(z)$ has all its poles outside the unit circle, you get a stable anti-causal filter.

Comment: Relief! The world is at piece again! Thanx very much.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a system is BIBO stable if (and only if)   G(z) 's poles are all contained within the unit circle (not on) and all  1/G(z) 's poles are outside the unit circle?

Comment: @Michelle: No, BIBO stability just means that the output is bounded for any bounded input signal. For a rational transfer function that means that there must be no poles *on* the unit circle. If you further require causality, all poles must be *inside* the unit circle. BIBO stability says nothing about the zeros of the transfer function, and, consequently, nothing about the poles of the inverse system.

Comment: As you can tell this is not my field of study but I am using the theory to explain my findings in another field involving difference equations and literature doesn't cover ''in theory'' type situations. If (1/G(z)) has all poles strictly inside the unit circle.. what can be said about the input/output relationship ?  (G(z) only has  poles at z=0)

Comment: @Michelle: I suggest you formulate a new question. It's getting a bit too cumbersome discussing it in the comments of this answer which is not directly related to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

If G(z) is causal and minimum phase than 1/G(z) is causal and minimum phase as well.

Non-minimum phase systems have a non-causal inverse. Simple example: a 2-tap delay has in inverse that is "-2" taps of delay, i.e. it is non-causal.

In addition you need $|G(z)|> 0$, otherwise you have division by zero problems. In practice you need $|G(z)|> \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a suitable small positive number, to avoid numerical and signal to noise problems.

This corresponds to the simple fact that whenever $|G(z)| = 0$  for some z, information is lost in the system and can therefore not be recovered.

Comment: What you said about $|G(z)|$ being non-zero is only valid for $|z|=1$. A system with $G(z)=0$ for $|z|<1$ can perfectly be inverted by a causal and stable system.